# In ECS, how are the different types of components typically stored?

Tags: entity-component-system

Consider an RPG for example, where one might have `PoisonComponent`, `BerserkComponent`, and `BlindComponent`. In a basic setup, let's say poison, berserk, and blind all work the same for everyone afflicted (i.e., every entity w/ a poison component will take the same amount of periodic damage).

It doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to create an instance of a class or a struct or anything for these, but then the different types of components should be stored somewhere, right?

What's typically the case for their storage? Like an XML or JSON file? Does it make sense to have each entity contain a list of just strings for components like this? (e.g., components that store no data). Similarly, what's the answer to this question for simple components that *do* store data (e.g., `HPComponent` has `maxHP` and `currentHP` or something).

I've read a lot about how an ECS system works, how it might be written in code, etc., but no one ever seems to talk about more abstract storage. Is the implication here that there are just a bunch of files that look like this:

```
class Component:
    pass

class HPComponent(Component)
    def __init__(self, max_hp: int = None, current_hp: int = None):
        self.max_hp = max_hp or 100
        self.current_hp = current_hp or 100

class ManaComponent(Component)
    def __init__(self, max_mana: int = None, current_mana: int = None):
        self.max_mana = max_mana or 100
        self.current_mana = current_mana or 100

# ... etc
```

... or JSON files that are read in somehow?

Comment: This post seems to be asking multiple questions; it looks like you're confused about how to get the entities from disk into the program. I've written [something about it](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/198935/40264) earlier this year. You might want to take a look first. Basically, you can organize your JSON/XML files in such a way that it describes an entity via its components. Then you need a class in your program that will parse this JSON and produce an Entity and/or a Component class.

Comment: _"It doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to create an instance of a class or a struct or anything for these"_ if you think that in your architecture and in your game a `PoisonComponent` is desirable and necessary, then in makes sense to create a class just for this. (As a side node, keep in mind though that _maybe_ it will be associated with a Timer (the Poison debuff will last for 3 seconds), and a strength/DamagePerSecond value, so you'll need more parameters anyway.) You could also be lazy and have a StatusComponent which will track Poison, Berserk, Blind effects, so only one new class.

Comment: Finally, keep in mind that there is no "ECS police". ECS are written in a way to accommodate a need; you can shape it in a way that will suit your needs in your language of choice.